# jQuery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been searching online for days now and not getting anywhere.
I've seen similar posts on here and have a general idea of what the problem is, but not sure how to fix it myself.

There is a conflict between my client's child theme, WP Bakery and WooCommerce. On the checkout page under customer details, when the country is changed the tax should auto-update (currently, it is set for Tax only for Australian clients).
When I change it to another country it does not auto-update and I get this error message in the inspect tool.

```css
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (checkout.min.js?ver=4.3.1:1)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3472)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3503)
```

This is the temporary domain I have it on currently: http://shannonp12.sg-host.com/checkout/

Below is the snippet from where the issue is on line 5 (checkout.min.js?ver=4.3.1:1)

```css
jQuery(function(g) {
    if ("undefined" == typeof wc_checkout_params)
        return !1;
    var v = {
        updateTimer: !(g.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.cursor = "default"),
        dirtyInput: !1,
        selectedPaymentMethod: !1,
        xhr: !1,
        $order_review: g("#order_review"),
        $checkout_form: g("form.checkout"),
        init: function() {
```

I hope that's enough information, please let me know if I need to provide more information.
Thanks in advance!

Followed Emre instruction

> Maybe something like this? updateTimer: !(g.blockUI && g.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.cursor == "default"),. It checks for the existence of g.blockUI before checking the cursor

Now getting this

```css
Uncaught TypeError: g(...).block is not a function
    at update_checkout_action
```

which points to this...

```css
                g(".woocommerce-checkout-payment, .woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table").block({
```

Comment: obviously `g.blockUI` is undefined, also does not make much sense doing this assignment at that time, cant you just remove this line?

Comment: Maybe something like this? `updateTimer: !(g.blockUI && g.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.cursor == "default"),`. It checks for the existence of `g.blockUI` before checking the cursor.

Comment: Thanks Emre, I've just edited original post.

Comment: @ShannonPayne it looks like this plugin is kinda missing http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element or not configured to work with `g` as Jquery

Comment: @johnSmith I'll have a look, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue. After debugging couples of hour I found that I linked jquery.mim.js in header.php. When I remove this then the coupon code and other functions of woocomerce work perfectly.